# How are the exchange boxes being rearranged on stackexchange.com/sites?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I couldn't seem to make sense of the JS on [stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites). It looks like there is some balancing, rotating etc. going on when you expand one of the stack exchange information boxes. I was wondering how this is being achieved? At least how is this likely being achieved in terms of its data structure and how it's being put into effect in this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It using optimization algorithm like bin-packing or treemap (kd-tree) and maximize packing density. When you insert or delete a tile it then finds the best position for the new tile and it can use a simple animation along the x and y axis (in jquery animate). Some jquery plugins can solve your problem: masonry, isotope, wookmark, freetile, vgrid, blocksit. Read here: http://webdesigninspirationtoday.com/article/367/5-jquery-plugins-to-produce-pinterest-like-dynamic-grid-layout. Normally optimization algorithm is useful for real life problems, like how to copy your music archive and not to waste space. Read here about the algorithmus on pinterest.com: http://www.quora.com/Pinterest/What-technology-is-used-to-generate-pinterest-coms-absolute-div-stacking-layout.